# How do I reverse the order of 16 bit registers di, si, bp and sp while only using the mov instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to reverse the order of some 16 bit registers that do not seem to have 8 bit counterparts. This is a homework assignment that I am stuck on.

I have successfully reversed the registers that have 8 bit registers as well as 16 bit. However I have no idea how I can reverse the registers that only have 16 bit. I am only allowed to use the mov instruction for this assignment.

I have tried moving the value of di into cx, then moving ch to dl and cl to dh, hoping that this would reverse the order. Then I did mov di, dx. This did not work as expected.

```
; Program Template

.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword

.data
    msgforward WORD 6 DUP(?)
    msgbackward WORD 6 DUP(?)
    restore_esp DWORD ?

.code
main proc
    mov restore_esp, esp ; save the contents of register ESP so it can be restored before the program finishes
    ; DO NOT REMOVE THIS

    ; clear the registers
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, 0
    mov edx, 0
    mov esi, 0
    mov edi, 0
    mov esp, 0
    mov ebp, 0

    ; store message 'Welcome Home" in reverse order across the six 16-bit registers.

    mov ax, "EM"
    mov bx, "OH"
    mov si, " E"
    mov di, "MO"
    mov sp, "CL"
    mov bp, "EW"

    ; PUT YOUR INSTRUCTIONS FOR PHASES 1-3 HERE
    ; PHASE 1

    mov [msgforward], bp
    mov [msgforward+2], sp
    mov [msgforward+4], di
    mov [msgforward+6], si
    mov [msgforward+8], bx
    mov [msgforward+10], ax

    ; PHASE 2
    ; Use ch and cl
    mov ch, bl
    mov cl, bh
    mov bp, cx

    mov cx, sp
    mov dx, cx
    mov sp, dx

    ;mov dx, di
    ;mov cl, dh
    ;mov ch, dl
    mov di, dx

    mov dx, si
    mov cl, dh
    mov ch, dl
    mov si, cx

    mov cl, bh
    mov ch, bl
    mov bx, cx

    mov cl, ah
    mov ch, al
    mov ax, cx

    ; PHASE 3
    ;mov [msgbackward+10], bp
    ;mov [msgbackward+8], sp
    mov [msgbackward+6], di
    mov [msgbackward+4], si
    mov [msgbackward+2], bx
    mov [msgbackward], ax

    mov esp, restore_esp ; restore register ESP to its original value so the program can end correctly.

    ; DO NOT REMOVE THIS
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: The code shown looks fine. What does it do that you do not expect?

Comment: That looks like a valid but slow way to emulate `rol si, 8` to byte-swap SI.  If you're restricted to only `mov`, I don't see a better way.

Comment: @prl The output that I get is not what the assignment shows as the correct output. I keep getting very mixed up output. The final output should be the string emoh emoclew. You basically have to reverse the string.

Comment: You need to show the full program. The problem is not in the part you showed.

Comment: @prl added the complete code as requested

Comment: *This did not work as expected.* isn't a detailed enough description for a [mcve].  Given that you were successfully byte-swapping one register, maybe you have a typo somewhere, like mixing up `bp` and bx`/bh/bl, or maybe you accidentally destroy some register values.  Use comments to keep track of what *should* be in what register, and **use a debugger** to single-step through and find when that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code successfully reverses ax, bx, and si. For di, sp, and bp use the same code as for si. (Note that bh and bl are parts of bx, not parts of bp. For bp, use cx and dx as intermediaries as you do for si.)

Comment: Be sure to proofread your code carefully to avoid typos, especially in the register names.